# removal of indirect cyclic object references in property map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this task. I have an object which can contain anything as a property value - array, object, primitive value, itself, and can have arbitrary nested properties (don't care about symbols).

I need to build a map of that object's properties like this.

```
const obj = {
    p1: 'this',
    p2: ['that'],
    p3: { q: 'other' }
}
```

to be turned into =>

```
["p1", "this"]
["p2/0", "that"]
["p3/q", "other"]
```

I have created code that can handle this stuff, arbitrary nesting, direct cyclic references and to some degree indirect cyclic references (that part needs some tweaking)

```
// holds result (path: value)
const result = new Map();

// holds already visited objects
// used later to check for circular references
const visited = new WeakMap();

const objTravesal = (o, path = '') => {
  const keys = Object.keys(o);
  keys.forEach(key => {

    // if the value is not an object
    // add it into results
    if (!(typeof o[key] === 'object')) {
      result.set((path + String(key)), o[key]);
    } else {
      // if the object has not been visited yet
      // or if has a same path prefix, proceed
      if (!visited.has(o) || visited.get(o) === path) {
        // prevent direct circular reference
        if (o !== o[key]) {
          visited.set(o, path);
          objTravesal(o[key], path + key + '/');
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

const meta = {
  info: '...'
}
meta.self = meta; // direct circular reference to meta

const obj = {
  label: 'myObj',
  metaInfo: meta,
  count: 3,
  additonal: {
    main: ['main1', 'main2'],
    secondary: ['secondar1', 'secondary2']
  }
}
obj.self = obj; // direct circular reference to obj

// here is the problem
obj.other = meta;
meta.other = obj;

objTravesal(obj);
console.log([...result]);
```

When run, it handles indirect cyclic references in the sense that it will not crush, but logs more than I would prefer.

E.g. in this particular case (part of the output).

```
// this is ok
["label", "myObj"]

// this should not be included as the information is already there
["metaInfo/other/label", "myObj"]
```

Does anyone have any idea how/where to change anything in the code above to achieve this?

Comment: If the *values* are unique (or, at least, are not to be repeated), can't you simply search the existing result for the value, and not append the new [key, value] array of the value already exists?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well maybe I could test the result somehow, I just don't know how exactly as direct testing would not help as it can be seen from the example above and slicing the result to test if the last part e.g `label: myObj` is not viable either, because another object could produce that same suffix and removing that would be an error (generally, values are not unique and can be repeated if produced by different objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to test for `if (!visited.has(o[key]))` instead of `if (!visited.has(o))`. The same applies to `visisted.set` - you should use the new object that you're looking at, not the old one.

In conclusion, you don't even need a `Map` to store the paths, a `Set` is enough for collecting visited objects. And you can save yourself much of a hassle by moving the typecheck and `visited` check to the front of the function, as the base case for your recursion:

```
function traverse(val, path = '', result = new Map, visited = new WeakSet) {
  if (typeof val != 'object' || val == null) {
    result.set(path, val);
  } else /* it's an object */ if (!visited.has(val)) {
    visited.add(val);
    for (const key in val) {
      traverse(val[key], path + '/' + key, result, visited);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

If you have an object structure with multiple references to the same object (not necessarily circular), and you want to output the shortest path to it, you will need to use a [bread-first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead of the current depth-first one.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't know how to reconstruct the desired output from the output of your function as it also contains that duplicate information.

Comment: Oops, I messed up my argument order. It doesn't output anything multiple times now.